# Android: Checking for empty EditText Fields

Tags: android, android-edittext, try-catch

I am working on an android project for personal interest. I am working with multiple EditText fields and all must be filled in to a non-zero decimal or integer.  I have specified in my xml file that it only accepts numbers or decimals. I am not too familiar with Java, but I have been reading into the try/catch method and how it is used when I am trying to parse each of the EditText values as a double. Right now, it runs fine when all of the fields are filled, but I want to add some kind of exception handling so that if by mistake you forget to enter a field, the application will display an error message instead of crashing. This sounds like a lot but I think it is pretty minor. Here is my calculating method that I am using. Thank you for your review :)

```
public static void calculate() {

    NumberFormat formatter1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    NumberFormat formatter2 = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");

    Editable evG1F = etG1F.getText();
    Editable evG1U = etG1U.getText();
    Editable evG2F = etG2F.getText();
    Editable evG2U = etG2U.getText();
    Editable evG3F = etG3F.getText();
    Editable evG3U = etG3U.getText();
    Editable evWin = etWin.getText();

    double g1f = 0.0;
    double g1u = 0.0;
    double g2f = 0.0;
    double g2u = 0.0;
    double g3f = 0.0;
    double g3u = 0.0;
    double p1odds, p2odds, p3odds, p4odds, p5odds, p6odds, p7odds, p8odds;
    double totalParlay, profit, finalOdds, risk;

    win = 0.0;

    g1f = Double.parseDouble(evG1F.toString());
    g1u = Double.parseDouble(evG1U.toString());
    g2f = Double.parseDouble(evG2F.toString());
    g2u = Double.parseDouble(evG2U.toString());
    g3f = Double.parseDouble(evG3F.toString());
    g3u = Double.parseDouble(evG3U.toString());
    win = Double.parseDouble(evWin.toString());

    p1odds = (1 / (g1f * g2f * g3f));
    p2odds = (1 / (g1f * g2f * g3u));
    p3odds = (1 / (g1f * g2u * g3f));
    p4odds = (1 / (g1f * g2u * g3u));
    p5odds = (1 / (g1u * g2f * g3f));
    p6odds = (1 / (g1u * g2f * g3u));
    p7odds = (1 / (g1u * g2u * g3f));
    p8odds = (1 / (g1u * g2u * g3u));

    totalParlay = (p1odds + p2odds + p3odds + p4odds + p5odds + p6odds
            + p7odds + p8odds);
    profit = 1 - totalParlay;
    finalOdds = ((profit / totalParlay) + 1);
    risk = (win / (finalOdds - 1));

    p1 = ((risk + win) * p1odds);
    p2 = ((risk + win) * p2odds);
    p3 = ((risk + win) * p3odds);
    p4 = ((risk + win) * p4odds);
    p5 = ((risk + win) * p5odds);
    p6 = ((risk + win) * p6odds);
    p7 = ((risk + win) * p7odds);
    p8 = ((risk + win) * p8odds);

    sRisk = risk;
    sFinalOdds = finalOdds;

    tvRisk.setText("$" + formatter1.format(Parlay.sRisk));
    tvOdds.setText("" + formatter2.format(Parlay.sFinalOdds));

}
```

Comment: This code cries for an array.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `parseDouble()` statements in a try/catch block:

```
    try {
        g1f = Double.parseDouble(evG1F.getText().toString());
        g1u = Double.parseDouble(evG1U.getText().toString());
        g2f = Double.parseDouble(evG2F.getText().toString());
        g2u = Double.parseDouble(evG2U.getText().toString());
        g3f = Double.parseDouble(evG3F.getText().toString());
        g3u = Double.parseDouble(evG3U.getText().toString());
        win = Double.parseDouble(evWin.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Error handling here
    }
```

The exception will get thrown if it's not a valid double, or if the string is empty. I've added the `getText()` before `toString()` on each call, because you really don't need to declare those `Editable` objects up further (since you are only using `getText()` on them anyway).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know if the Editable variables needed to be declared or not.

Comment: also if I am not using the declared Editable variables, I think it should be etG1F.getText().toString()